# Values of FormGroup are not assigned to FormData

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, multipartform-data

I need to upload multi-part data to my api. So I created a FormData in order to upload. First I get all the data of the user input which are the following: image(file), category(string). The data is actually taken thanks to the template and is stored in `categoryForm: FormGroup`. Then I want to store the values in a `FormData`. But sadly when I want to upload the payload to the api it spits out the following error:

```
{"src":["No file was submitted."],"tag":["This field is required."]}
```

When I looked at the console I noticed that the FormData object is actually empty. So the values of `categoryForm` were not reassigned to `formData`. There is no problem with categoryForm and the template I think, since when I log them. I get an object with the data, also when I log `category` and `image` separately I get data.
So the problem must be in the section where I want to assign the values of `categoryForm` to `formData`. Can you help me further with this problem?

**Code**

```
  apiSubmit() {
      console.log(this.categoryForm.value) // returns values
      console.log(this.categoryForm.get('category').value); // returns values
      console.log(this.categoryForm.get('image').value); // returns values
      
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('category', this.categoryForm.get('category').value);
      formData.append('image', this.categoryForm.get('image').value);
      console.log(formData); // doesn't return values
    
      this.http.post<any>(this.url, formData, httpOptions).subscribe(
        (res) => console.log(res),
        (err) => console.log(err)
      );
    }]
```

**Console Logs**

[image: console]

Comment: is that output of console.log(this.categoryForm.get('image').value); in console log?

Comment: @Vinay yes its actually the log below the "hallo". Its the file log. "Hallo" is the category log.

Comment: Why are you getting file data inside ZoneAwarePromise? You cannot access data inside promise like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way you have done will not work in that context because of `append` to the object instead of that use constructor for `FormData` which accepts `this.categoryForm.value` as arguments or parameter and assign it to the variable or else you can directly use `this.categoryForm.value` a post method instead of `FormData`

For ex:

```
export class FormData{
   image: any;
   category: string;
  
  constructor(args){
     this.image = args.image;
     this.category = args.category;
  }
}
```

and you can create an object like `const formData = new FormData(this.categoryForm.value);`

Comment: can you paste your solution or you think how it will work into my code snippet above. I don't really get how I should implement  your proposal.

Comment: you need to design your class in such a way that how you need data in a format

Comment: this gives me an error when I want to implement it:( like that? : `constructor(
    args,
    private router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient) {
      this.image = args.image;
      this.category = args.category
  }`

Comment: don't include this in component constructor this approach is for normal oops pattern create class and assigning values to it or lets say creating object

Comment: Thanks it worked. The formData is now filled with information. Sadly the api still says that there was nothing submitted but I think its an mistake with my api call.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue with image uploads with form data.
First of all, you can use an npm package called 'serialize' to convert an object to a form data without having to keep writing 'append' all the time. And to log form data values to console, you use...

for (var value of formData.values()) { console.log(value); }

From my experience, the best way to handle image upload to a server on ionic is by using 'base64' encoded string. So I suggest you modify your backend to accept 'base64' encoded string.

Most of the camera native plugins in ionic either returns FILE_URI or BASE64.

For example, using the camera native plugin.

Following the documentation, run the installation
[ionic camera native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera)

```ts
openGallery() {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
    };

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
     const base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
     console.log(base64Image);
     this.categoryForm.value.image = base64Image;
    }, (err) => {
     console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

With this and your backend set to accept base64 string, everything should work.